# Pivoting data in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I've just gotten into working with a Neo4J database, and I'm having a hard time figuring out a good way to pivot some data that I'm working with.

I have a basic query that looks like this:
`MATCH (n:DATA) WHERE n.status =~ "SUCCESS" return n.group as Group, n.label as Label, avg(toFloat(n.durationMillis)/60000) as Minutes`, which produces tall narrow data like this:

```
|Group  |Label  |Minutes|
|-------|-------|-------|
|group1 |label1 |1.0    |
|group1 |label2 |2.0    |
|group1 |label3 |5.0    |
|group2 |label1 |3.0    |
|group2 |label3 |2.0    |
...
```

What I would like to do is pivot this data to provide a short wide view as a summary table:

```
| Group | label1 | label2 | label3 |
| ----- | ------ | ------ | ------ |
|group1 | 1.0    | 2.0    | 5.0    |
|group2 | 3.0    | -      | 2.0    |
...
```

Is there a simple way to do this with Cypher?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for Neo4j tools (like the Neo4j Browser) to generate a visualization that looks like a pivot table from a Cypher query, the query would have to *hardcode* the headings for each "column" -- since a Cypher query cannot dynamically generate the names of the values it returns. That is, your `RETURN` clause would have to look something like `RETURN Group, label1, label2, label3`.

Now, if you do happen to know all the possible labels beforehand, then you can indeed perform a simple query that returns your pivot table. For example:

```
MATCH (n:DATA)
WHERE n.status =~ "SUCCESS"
WITH n.group as Group, n.label AS l, AVG(n.durationMillis/60000.0) AS m
WITH Group, apoc.map.fromLists(COLLECT(l), COLLECT(m)) AS lmMap
RETURN Group,
  lmMap['label1'] AS label1,
  lmMap['label2'] AS label2,
  lmMap['label3'] AS label3
```

The APOC function [apoc.map.fromLists](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/data-structures/map-functions/#map-functions) returns a map generated from lists of keys and values. If a `Group` does not have a particular label, its cell value will be `null`.

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely a good start. I should be able to fix my column names and just update the query periodically as necessary.