# NEO4J: RETURN n{.*} to columns with distinct keys(n) as headers

Tags: neo4j

```
MATCH (n:Nodes)
RETURN n {.*}
```

Returns array for each row.

I'd like to split the arrays into columns. Is there a way to do this?

```
MATCH (n:Nodes)
WITH keys(n) as headers
UNWIND headers as rows
RETURN DISTINCT rows
```

Returns all the existing keys.

I'd like to turn these rows into column headers to return values for, so there would be null for any Nodes missing that property.

I tried:

```
MATCH (n:Nodes)
WITH keys(n) as headers
UNWIND headers as rows
WITH DISTINCT rows as headers
MATCH (n:Nodes)
RETURN n.[headers]
```

Yields 'Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input '[': expected an identifier, whitespace, a function name or a property key name (line 6, column 10 (offset: 119))'

```
MATCH (n:Nodes)
WITH keys(n) as headers
UNWIND headers as rows
WITH DISTINCT rows as headers
MATCH (n:Nodes)
RETURN headers, n[headers]
```

RETURNS each property value in its own row (not column).

Seems like there should be a way to do this. Most greatful for any pointers!

Comment: doesn't seem there is anything programatically, you would need to define the desired output columns. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63158937/pivoting-data-in-cypher

Comment: Thanks - I will study that pivot thread.  I was hoping I wouldn't have to type in all the possible properties as it's hundreds (I'm exporting to csv  and doing the pivot in xl right now which is an added step/pain). Hopefully they will implement a solution for this, as it seems pretty basic. Thanks again!